# Factor Group $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a small question concerning the elements of the factor group $G = \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}$. Are they simply the Irrationals composed with $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: What does "irrationals composed with $\Bbb Q$" mean? Do you know what "factor group" means? Do you know what groups, subgroups and cosets are?

Comment: Yes I do, but I am trying to grasp the concepts a litte bit better. As far as I know, the factor group consists of the subgroups where left and right cosets are equal(normal subgroups). The elements of the factor groups are then the representatives of the different normal subgroups. In this case I was wondering what the representatives are of RmodQ. Q is a normal subgroup of R depending on the composition endowed upon R. Two elements of R lie in the same normal subgroup if they differ by an Element of Q.

Comment: Therefore shouldn't any element out of the Irrational numbers be a representative for the normal subgroups, as they all lie in different normal subgroups?

Comment: You're mixing up the terms subgroup and coset. Make sure you know all the definitions and really understand them. No, not every pair of irrational numbers represents distinct cosets - indeed, as you intimated in the last sentence of your first comment, two elements of $\Bbb R$ are representatives for the same coset if they differ by a rational number. Thus, for instance, $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}+1$ both represent the same coset of $\Bbb Q$ even though both are irrational. It is impossible for $H$'s set complement to be a set of coset representatives of $H$, except in very rare circumstances.

Comment: Also, there isn't really any good choice of trasversal for $\Bbb R/\Bbb Q$. Sorry! (The term transversal means "set of coset representatives." Note that there are many possible transversals in general - you get to select which representative of each coset you want at your whim.)

Comment: Won't the elements just be all irrational numbers which aren't of the form (something irrational) + (something rational)?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, and you are right that what I said is wrong. What I meant to say was what man_in_green_shirt said in the last comment. The factor groups are, in the end a group of equivalence classes, and it does not matter which representative we choose, as they are all equivalent.

Comment: @anon Thank you for the explanation, it helped to clarify a few things for me.

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt The only numbers that are not of the form (irrational)+(rational) are the rational numbers themselves, and every rational number is a representative for the identity element of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 5):

If we consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ then it is not difficult to see that $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}\simeq \mathbb{R}$ (as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$). It implies that $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}\simeq \mathbb{R}$ as groups.

Comment: What is this isomorphism?

Comment: @Bernard There are infinitely many isomorphisms. Constructing one requires using choice from set theory.

Comment: @Bernard: Using the axiom of choice, there exists a basis $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ which contains the basis $\{1\}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. It follows that the set of cosets of $\mathbb{Q}$ that contain the elements of $B-\{1\}$ are a basis for $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$. Any bijection $f : B \to B-\{1\}$ then induces an isomorphism $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

As abstract groups, $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are isomorphic. As topological groups, however, they are different. In fact,
the quotient topology on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ is the trivial topology, hence not very interesting. 
This follows from the fact that preimages of open sets must be open and saturated. Thus if such a preimage is nonempty, it contains an open interval, and since it is saturated, it must contain all real numbers which differ by a rational from a point in this interval. Then it follows that this set must be all of ℝ. Thus the only saturated open sets of ℝ are ∅ and ℝ itself. Hence the quotient topology is trivial.